# how to fit image to label in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So in python i have a Label that I'm using to display images. But the images are rather large and they exceed the size of the label. Is there a way to load the images to fit the label without resizing them?

here is what i do now.

```
labelWidth = top.winfo_screenwidth()
labelHeight = top.winfo_screenheight() 
maxsize = (labelWidth, labelHeight)
im.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
```

but this takes way to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
im = im.resize(maxsize)
```

instead of:

```
im.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```