# Problems displaying video in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, image-resizing

I'm trying to create a GUI that opens a video and an image below it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter, tkMessageBox 
import ttk

import cv2
import sys

width, height = 800, 600
banner = cv2.imread('../data/banner.png')
b,g,r = cv2.split(banner)
banner = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
im = Image.fromarray(banner)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../data/sample.mov')


root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
root.title("Contador")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

lmain = Tkinter.Label(root)
lmain.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
bmain = Tkinter.Label(root)
bmain.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='nsew')
baner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
bmain.configure(image=baner)

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        return
#    labelWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
#    labelHeight = root.winfo_screenheight() 
#    maxsize = (labelWidth, labelHeight)
#    frame = frame.resize(maxsize)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(frame)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)

show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

The problems I'm having are the following:

- I need to resize the image to fit the label.
- the commented part i got from here ([how to fit image to label in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997669/how-to-fit-image-to-label-in-python)) but it gives a channel number error(line 40) and further down the code gives a NoneType error(line 41) and a invalid type of image(numpy array) in line 42
- the image and video don't change size when resizing the window

So I need solution for this tkinter code(or even a better framework for python)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to resize after every frame? Why not do `root.bind("<Configure>", resize_frame)` and only resize when needed? The `winfo_screenwidth()` and `winfo_screenheight()` calls should return always the same value as long as you stay on the same screen. You are resizing `frame` but are you resizing its parent container?

Comment: I'm resizing every frame because the video starts off as bigger than the label and i haven't found a way for it to stick to the labels size.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.
Turns out the line I got from another question:

```
frame = frame.resize(maxsize)
```

should be:

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame, maxsize)
```

Also to get the label's size the command is:

```
labelWidth = lmain.winfo_width()
labelHeight = lmain.winfo_height()
```

since

```
labelWidth = root.winfo_width()
labelHeight = root.winfo_height()
```

gets the root's size not the label's.